# Coloring in php using HSL

Tags: php, html, css, hsl

I want to be able to color some letters (bases) in a sequence.  I can make a function to say 'color this' but I can not say what the color is.

I have made some hsl divs using an internal stylesheet but this doesn't seem to work.

```
case 1: /*500-550(Raw Score)*/
    $truecol=<div style="text-color: hsl($col,25%, 100%);">/*input*/</div>
    break;

case 2: //550-600
    $truecol=<div style="text-color: hsl($col,35%, 100%);">/*input*/</div>
    break;
case 3: //600-650
    $truecol=<div style="text-color: hsl($col,45%, 50%);">/*input*/</div>
    break;
case 4: //650-700
    $truecol=<div style="text-color: hsl($col,50%, 100%);">/*input*/</div>
    break;
case 5: //700-750
    $truecol=<div style="text-color: hsl($col,55%, 100%);">/*input*/</div>
    break;
case 6: //750-800
    $truecol=<div style="text-color: hsl($col,60%, 100%);">/*input*/</div>
    break;
case 6: //800-850
    $truecol=<div style="text-color: hsl($col,70%, 100%);">/*input*/</div>
    break;
case 7: //850-900
    $truecol=<div style="text-color: hsl($col,80%, 100%);">/*input*/</div>
    break;
case 8: //900-950
    $truecol=<div style="text-color: hsl($col,90%, 100%);">/*input*/</div>
    break;
case 9: //950-1000
    $truecol=<div style="text-color: hsl($col,100%, 100%);">/*input*/</div>
    break;
```

Do I have to convert rgb to hsl saturation, then back to hexadecimal? 
It is important that the colors go in a gradient.  This is why I use HSL initially.

Comment: Regardless, with 100% lightness, all (but one) of these will just be white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, just look at the colour-coding of your PHP in the question. Clearly you can see it's not right.

Put those HTML tags in a string. Preferably with double-quotes, as long as you escape the style attribute correctly. Example:

```
$truecol = "<div style=\"color: hsl($col,100%,50%);\">...</div>";
```

Also notice I corrected the other two errors: The style property is `color`, not <del>`text-color`</del>, and in `hsl` the lightness should be 50% for a "normal" colour. At 100% you just get white.